# Dynamic array of views in Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, android-view

I am trying to create dynamic `TextView` by creating an array of `TextViews` but getting error :

```
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=0; index=0
```

> My Code:

```
var txtViews = arrayOfNulls<TextView>(3)
    for (i in txtViews.indices) {
        txtViews = arrayOfNulls(i)
        txtViews[i]?.textSize = 24.0F
        txtViews[i]?.text = "Hello"
        txtViews[i]?.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this,
        R.color.colorAccent))
        layout.addView(txtViews[i])
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You never initialized those null references inside your array:

This should work for what you are trying to achieve:

```
val txtViews = arrayOfNulls<TextView>(3)
        for (i in txtViews.indices) {
            txtViews[i] = TextView(context).apply {
                textSize = 24.0F
                text = "Hello"
                setTextColor(
                    ContextCompat.getColor(context,
                        R.color.colorAccent))
            }
            layout.addView(txtViews[i])
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

> There was no need to create **arrayOfNulls**

I did this way:

```
for (i in size) {
        val txtView = TextView(this).apply {
            textSize = 24.0F
            text = Html.fromHtml("&#8226")
            setTextColor(
                ContextCompat.getColor(
                    context,
                    R.color.colorAccent
                )
            )
        }

        layout.addView(txtView)
    }
```